# Pentaho Report Designer CE Copy & Paste not working

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

The Paste option is always greyed out.

Steps to reproduce here are easy:

- Start a new report or open an existing one
- Add a field or element into any of the bands
- Edit -> Copy (or Right-click -> Copy)

[image: demonstration]

Apparently, there is an exception being thrown, listed below. Every time I click copy, the `NoClassDef` exception repeats.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.SerializedObjectContainer.<init>(SerializedObjectContainer.java:133)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.GenericTransferable.<init>(GenericTransferable.java:42)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.util.dnd.ClipboardManager.setContents(ClipboardManager.java:95)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.global.CopyAction.actionPerformed(CopyAction.java:69)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:374)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1029)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1073)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private int java.io.ObjectOutputStream.depth accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @31740674
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:181)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.SerializedObjectContainer$DebuggingObjectOutputStream.<clinit>(SerializedObjectContainer.java:44)
    ... 41 more


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.SerializedObjectContainer$DebuggingObjectOutputStream
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.SerializedObjectContainer.<init>(SerializedObjectContainer.java:133)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.GenericTransferable.<init>(GenericTransferable.java:42)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.util.dnd.ClipboardManager.setContents(ClipboardManager.java:95)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.global.CopyAction.actionPerformed(CopyAction.java:69)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:374)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1029)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1073)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private int java.io.ObjectOutputStream.depth accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @31740674 [in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:181)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.SerializedObjectContainer$DebuggingObjectOutputStream.<clinit>(SerializedObjectContainer.java:44)
    ... 41 more
```

A brief research pointed me towards the argument `--add-opens` to the java runtime. The bat file has this already in, but apparently only for Java 11. For tests, I added the following lines to make sure they are executed

```
set JAVA_ADD_OPENS=--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED
set JAVA_LOCALE_COMPAT=-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,SPI
```

This unfortunately did not have any effect whatsoever.

I'm using Windows 10 22H2 and Pentaho Report Designer 9.4.0.0.-343 (although I tried on 9.3 and had the same issue)

Any idea what can be done to further troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho 9.4 works with Oracle or OpenJDK 11: https://docs.hitachivantara.com/r/en-us/pentaho-data-integration-and-analytics/9.4.x/mk-95pdia000/components-reference/java-virtual-machine

I fixed it by setting environment variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME to Oracle JDK java 11 home path.